# white space around an img tag within a th

Tags: html, css

[image: img space]

This question involves the black box from the picture (it is a `<th>` tag).

The `<th>` tag ends up with a height of 23px. The images are 18px by 18px. Where's the 5px bottom margin coming from and how to I get rid of it?

borders, padding, and margins are all set to 0. manually setting the height of the `<tr>` and the `<th>` tag to 18px doesn't do anything. Anything below 23px has no effect.

Help!

Comment: Post up the page or a fiddle.

Comment: Any chance you could make a fiddle that demonstrates your problem?

What about browsers, only some or all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are inline elements, so they are placed on a text line in the element. The images are aligned on the base line of the text, so there is a gutter below the base line used for hanging characters like g and j. The extra space is that gutter.

You can get rid of the space by turning the images into block elements. As you want the images beside each other, using the style `float:left;` would make them block elements and line them up.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have white spaces around the images in your html source code?
If yes, try removing them:

```
<th><img src="..." alt="" /></th>
```

Comment: This, for the most part works, but I think changing to block alignment is better.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use `float:left` if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably the `line-height`. Try setting it to zero. Sample HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/16/16">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/16/16">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
td {
    background: #000;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4VMTV/

Try the above with and without the `line-height: 0` and you should see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) or [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/fx/)+[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), you can right-click the `th` and inspect the element. This will provide additional detail that will help you to determine what padding or margin is being added, and why.